# linker input file unused because linking not done, I can't get .o

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have a template class of a binary tree, tree.tpp and tree.h. I have done a test with the class but I can't compile  it

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "arbolbinario.h"

 using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ArbolBinario<int> pila(45);


    return 0;
}
```

And I'm having the following error when I do: g++ -c -o ./tree.o ./tree.tpp -I ./tree.h

g++: warning: ./tree.tpp: linker input file unused because linking not done

(I'm working with netbeans)

Comment: I have added an important "However" part to my answer that I think is relevant to you. (You did not show a full [repro], so I can not say for sure). Please read that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.tpp` is not one of the file endings recognized by `g++`, see [its documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html).

Therefore `g++` assumes that you want the file to be passed to the linker directly. But since you used the `-c` flag, which indicates that you want `g++` to only compile, but *not* invoke the linker, you get that error message.

The solution is to tell `g++` what kind of file it is that you are passing it explicitly:

```
g++ -c -o ./tree.o -x c++ ./tree.tpp -I ./tree.h
```

or, better, rename your C++ source file use one of the common file endings for C++ source files, e.g. `.cpp`, `.cc`, `.cxx`, etc. That would result in less trouble with build tools and less confusion for others looking at your project.

---

As noted in the question comments `-I ./tree.h` also is clearly wrong, but not the cause of this particular error (and probably it just doesn't belong there at all).

---

**However**:

If your `.tpp` contains the implementation of methods of a class template, then you should *not* rename it (`.tpp` is appropriate in that case), but you also should *not* compile it as translation unit at all. That means it should *not appear* in any `g++` command.

`.tpp` files implementing a template classes methods need to be included in the `.h` file with the class template definition, instead. Otherwise you will get linker errors later when you try to link your files, see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Answer (score 2):

The `-c` flag tells GCC to only compile the input source files, *not* to do any linking.

If you want the compiler to link the object files into an executable binary, you need to remove the `-c` flag.